# Node js req.session not working when trying to access it from react js fetch command

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I have created a backend middleware which checks if a user is logged in or not.
This functions handle the login route and initialise the req.session.

```
router.post("/login", upload.none(), async function (req, res) {
console.log("API");
const curr_email = req.body.email
const curr_password = req.body.password

let login_res = await User_functions.loginUser(req, curr_email, curr_password)
if (login_res == -1 || login_res == false) {
    return res.send({error:"Wrong username or password"})
}
req.session.LoggedIn = true
req.session.user_id = login_res['user_id']
console.log("Successfully logged in !!!")
return res.redirect("/users")
});
```

This is the middleware which helps with authentication.

```
const requiresLogin = (req, res, next) => {
console.log("req.session",req.session)
if (req.session && req.session.user_id) {
    return next();
} else {
    console.log("User not logged in")
    return res.status(400).json({error:'You must be logged in to view this page.'})
}
}
```

Now, using postman, this works as expected. User can only access specific URL's when logged in. But when I fetch the same URL using React js, after login in it fails. I can't figure out the reason for this.
This is my react js login control.

```
handleSubmit(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    const requestOptions = {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
        body: JSON.stringify({ email: this.state.username,password : this.state.password })
    };
    let first = process.env.REACT_APP_URL
    let second_arg = "login"
    let url = first + second_arg
    fetch(url, requestOptions)
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => {
        if('error' in data){
            alert("Failed");
        }
        else{
            // let history = useHistory();

            // this.history.push("/dashboard");
            this.props.history.push('/dashboard');

        }
    })
}
```

After redirecting if I try to access a protected route, I get alert that user is not logged in.

```
componentDidMount(){
    const requestOptions = {
        method: 'GET',
        headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
        body: JSON.stringify()
    };
    const  userId  = this.props.match.params["user_id"];

    let first = process.env.REACT_APP_URL
    const url = first + "users/" + userId
    console.log(url)
    fetch(url, requestOptions)
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => {
        if('error' in data){
            alert(data['error']);
        }
        else{
            console.log(data)
            this.setState({ user: data })
        }
    })
}
```

Stuck on this problem for 2 days now. Don't know what I am missing here. Can't find a reason for this anywhere on the internet also. Most folks have used JWT.
The complete frontend code is here :- https://github.com/dhruvdesmond/nutrify_frontend.
And backend is at :- https://github.com/dhruvdesmond/nutrify_backend

Comment: Seems like your componentDidMount is not async. Don't really know how much this is a problem when using fetch, but could you try it with ```async componentDidMount()```?

Comment: It seems you have used multer as a middleware on the backend, which makes the API accept only form-data requests, so your JSON won't be recognized. Most likely, if you won't upload anything, just remove the upload.none() middleware.

Comment: REST API's are stateless, so you either need to pass token or session cookie while making API requests.

Comment: @Gh05d adding async did not help.

Comment: @Ncifra Removing upload.none() also didn't help.

Comment: Backend code can be found here https://github.com/dhruvdesmond/nutrify_backend , if It helps.

Comment: When you log out email and password in the middleware, do they have the expected values or are they undefined or something other strange?

Comment: After logout I destroy the session. But problem is with login.

Comment: Session management is missing for the express app, you can use http://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/session.html

Comment: @NageshDhope It is not missing. It is working perfectly on POSTMAN. I just didn't added it here.

Comment: Do you host the frontend and backend on the same domain? In order to keep a state between two requests and make `req.session` work, cookies are used, and they won't work if the frontend and backend are hosted on different domains

Comment: @GuerricP They both have different ports.My point is all frontend is doing is making a request, just like postman. If it is working for POSTMAN, it should also work the same for REACT.

Comment: I found this a little similar, but can't understand it properly.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48039689/every-time-react-sends-request-to-express-a-new-session-is-generated

Comment: How is your session middleware configured?

Comment: @slebetman requiresLogin added the middleware above. It checks if req.session exists or not.

Comment: I'm not talking about your middleware. How did you configure the express-session middleware? Or are you using another session middleware?

Comment: var session = require('express-session')
router.use(session({
    secret: 'keyboard cat',
    resave: true,
    saveUninitialized: false,
    cookie: {
        maxAge: 60000
    }

Comment: This is also similar. But not working for me. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21093787/req-session-undefined-and-req-session-user-id-not-working

Comment: @DhruvSingh Postman actually sends back cookies in every subsequent request, but that might not be the case if the frontend and backend are not hosted on the same port. Can you confirm that you can see the backend cookie sent back by the frontend in every request?

Comment: @GuerricP Yes I can. But it is resetted.

Comment: @GuerricP If I don't use sessions what are my other choices.